# Datadome captcha of Vinted

Tags: web-scraping, cookies

I'm working with Vinted Captchas API endpoint (https://www.vinted.it/api/v2/captchas).
I've sent a request with same body as Chrome devtools:

> {"entity_type":"login","payload":{"username":MY_EMAIL}}

I got a 403 with a captcha:

```json
{
    "url": "https://geo.captcha-delivery.com/captcha/?initialCid=AHrlqAAAAAMADFeblMxINTAARLfR2Q==&cid=FEjxE25cRK8Rglj0johFLCrpcDwVu0jnRQ4ChfngEwgTCOt4GGzXFVvaqCzERpnGg6LTM1f6fHdh9Ni5P8qpCeuRz5C5AH9BhqJvZMBo9mAL_cmaZsvueDcOXt_pDFgy&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vinted.it%2Fapi%2Fv2%2Fcaptchas&hash=E6EAF460AA2A8322D66B42C85B62F9&t=bv&s=42855&e=149c6acc6bbeef9e3aade86f80cb9201b8a382df664b3af3dcc11911830873b0"
}
```

After solved that I got a cookie to set:

```
datadome=zW9JZ7oN4DcqnpwFy[OMITTED]lFvaI0W4eXTIkCdW8YTn0dg5TDJrLG8zfyfcmFnh_EgxSLtw2~WrcRZEjjO9~znAo5w_VluSoKabv;
```

what should I do with this cookie?
If I set on same request and send again it always give me a new captcha-delivery URL.